# OpenCL vstoren does not store vector in scalar array

Tags: opencl

I have the kernel as below.
My question is why is vstore8 not working? When the output is printed in the host code, it only returns 0s.
I put an "if(all(v == 0) == 1)" in the code to check whether the error was caused when I copy the values from int4* to int8 in v, but it was not that.
It seems like vstoren is doing nothing.
I am new to OpenCL so any help is appreciated.

```
__kernel void select_vec(__global int4 *input1,
                        __global int *input2,
                        __global int *output){

    //copy values in input arrays to vectors
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int4 vA = input1[i];
    int4 vB = input1[i+1];
    __private int8 v = (int8)(vA.s0, vA.s1, vA.s2, vA.s3, vB.s0, vB.s1, vB.s2, vB.s3);
    __private int8 v1 = vload8(0, input2);
    __private int8 v2 = vload8(1, input2);
    int8 results;
    
    if(any(v > 10) == 1){
        //if there is any of the elements in v that are greater than 10
        // copy the corresponding elements from v1 for elements greater than 10
        // for elements less than or equal to 17, copy the corresponding elements from v2
        results = select(v1, v2, v > 10);
    }else{
        //results is the combination of the first half of v2 and v2
        results = (int8) (v1.lo, v2.lo);
    }
    
    /* for testing of the error is due to vstoren */
    // results = (int8) (1);
    
    //store results in output array
    vstore8(results, i, output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `int8 v1 = vload8(i+0, input2);`, `int8 v2 = vload8(i+1, input2);` and `vstore8(results, i, output);`?

Currently you read from the same memory addresses in `input2` (0-7 for `v1` and 8-15 for `v2`) and write to the same memory address in `output` (0-7) with *all* threads. This is a race condition because depending on `v` and the last thread writing to `output`, you can get randomly different results. But if `input2` starts with `0s` in addresses 0-15 and `output` is initialized with all `0s`, it will remain all `0s`.

Comment: Did you do an `enqueueReadBuffer` for `output` and `queue.finish()` after the kernel call and before checking results?